# ivy:findrevision is not able to resolve a custom pattern in Artifactory, however ivy:retrieve does it

Tags: ivy, artifactory

I have this pattern in my ivysettings file:

```
<artifact pattern="${artifactory_host}/${repo}/[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/[type]/[artifact]-[revision].[ext]" />
```

When I resolve my dependencies with **ivy:retrieve** it gets the dependencies without any problem from Artifactory. But when I try to do it with **ivy:findrevision** it always set the type and the extension of the artifact as **jar**.

For instance if the path of the artifact is:

```
my_company/my_module/0.0.123456/cookbook/my_module_coockbooks-0.0.123456.zip
```

ivy:findrevision looks for:

```
my_company/my_module/0.0.123456/jar/my_module_coockbooks-0.0.123456.jar
```

Previously we had a **NFS ivy-repository** and ivy:findrevisions worked as good as ivy:retrieve, looking for the corresponding type and extension.

As far as I know the host, in this case Artifactory, shouldn't affect any resolve feature from ant-ivy because at the very end the resolution logic and pathfinding depends exclusively on the client side, in this case ant-ivy.

**UPDATE**

Ok, I found a simple work around but still not a real solution, I added another patter to the resolver, hardcoding the type and the extension.

```
<artifact pattern="${artifactory_host}/${repo}/[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/cookboock/[artifact]-[revision].zip" />
```

I really need to use ivy:findrevision for build logic in my ant-build and I don't want to have a different pattern for each type of artifact.